# I have a process called “watchbog” that is completely hogging my CPU and I don't know what it is

Tags: malware, linux, virus, debian

This process that has come out of nowhere is hogging my CPU and I have no clue what it is or how to get rid of it. You can see in the image below what it's doing:

[image: Process that is hogging my CPU]

What is this process? How can I get rid of it?

Every time I kill the process, it spawns back up within a minute or less.

Someone on stackoverflow suggested I come here instead.

Comment: FYI you don't need to create a separate account for security.stackexchange.com, you can use your stackoverflow account.

Comment: BTW, can you put that file (/bin/watchbog) and any related files into password protected archive and post it somewhere?

Comment: A Google search shows that watchbog may be related to known malware.

Comment: Unfortunately, we are not a malware removal site. Google says that it is malware.

Comment: Seems likely that it's mining malware.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get rid of the "watchbog" process?

One of the great things about Linux is that you can just redeploy it free. I highly suggest you just wipe your OS and re-install. Trouble shooting the virus is almost always an exercise in futility in my experience. So backing up files and doing a re-install is good ROI.

If you really want to get rid of the process without reinstall, start with a "locate" for it. It's running as ./ so it's most likely local somewhere on the file system. Chances are it's got a sister process that will re-install it if you delete it, but I'd start by hunting down the location of ./watchbog and then seeing if it's a binary or script and go from there.

Comment: watchbog cannot be located. Is there any way to locate its hidden location?